# HTML how to post a null or test saying "An image is not found" if the Image isn't available

Tags: html

We have a response that comes back from errors in an application that sends an HTML message posting an image of a quick break down of the application. But if the image doesn't exist the alert fails.

How can I add something on the below to either not post the image or set text to say the image does not exist or needs to be created?

```
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="cid:myUniqueCID"  style="width:800px;height:200px" /> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alt` attribute as `alt="Image not available"`, if image not available, it will show text instead of.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="cid:myUniqueCID" alt="Image not available"  style="width:800px;height:200px" /> 
    </td>
</tr>
```